# French Citizenship Application for France

Tags: france, citizenship, family, passport

I have been working in France with passeport talent for 5 years now. My family (wife and kids of age 7-10yrs now) joined me in France 4 years ago.

Can I file an application for citizenship of myself as well as my wife and children? Or should I apply after it’s been 5 years since my children started living in France? Or kids can only apply for citizenship after they are 18 years of age?

Really appreciate some knowledge about laws surrounding this scenario if anyone has had same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply as soon as you qualify, you do not have to wait for anybody. Your wife wouldn't automatically qualify because you do and consequently wouldn't become French immediately. She will have to wait to qualify herself.

By contrast, your children could become French as soon as you do (that's called *effect collectif*). It's not necessary for them to wait to be 18 or to have resided 5 years in France, the only requirements are:

- Being younger than 18
- Residing with you
- Being mentioned on the application